# Creating a Phonegap based Android ap in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-studio

I've dabbled with Phonegap using Eclipse and the ADT plugins in the past and I'm now trying to get my head around doing this in the new Android Studio IDE.

Since Phonegap v3 seems to rely on some kind of NodeJS commandline installation thingy, of which I know absolutely nothing about, I've downloaded Phonegap v2.9 instead. Also since Android Studio is so new and the documentation seems to only cover importing existing Eclipse projects or projects built using Phonegap's commandline, I'm instead trying to follow old Eclipse documentation.

To get to the point, I've created a project in Android Studio and verified that it runs. I've then created /assets/www and copied cordova.js and a basic index.html file in. I've copied cordova-2.9.0.jar in to /libs and right clicked to 'add as library'. Finally, I've amended MainActivity.java and AndroidManifest.xml accordingly.

The problem though is that when the build gets to 'import org.apache.cordova.*;' in my MainActivity.java file, it's erroring out with 'Gradle: package org.apache.cordova does not exist'.

Could somebody please point me in the direction of some documentation on creating a Phonegap ap using Android Studio (rather than importing in from Eclipse or from something created via Phonegap commandline), or even just describe how I'm supposed to edit the build.gradle file so that Gradle can find Cordova?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I gave up and did it the nodejs way, but I'd still appreciate some knowledge dumping by somebody who's gotten the above method to work.

Comment: I hope this link would be useful: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/05/16/phonegap-android-studio/

please inform me to prepare the answer from it's content.

Answer (score 4):

Ric is really easy to work with Phonegap and ANDROID Studio.
Here is what i am doing:

1. Creating Phonegap project: ***phonegap create testproject com.testproject.name Name***;
2. Enter Project directory: ***cd testproject***;
3. Add Android platform: ***phonegap build android***;

You have your phonegap project ready. Now open Android Studio. Select Import project and follow instructions. If you don't have any plugins added in your project it's preaty pushing ***NEXT*** till you get to the end.

That's all. If you need more information tell me will be happy to help you.

If you prefer snapshot you can find a very easy to follow tutorial here:
[Phonegap and Android studio](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/05/16/phonegap-android-studio/)

Comment: When I try to follow these steps using Android Studio 1.0 and Phonegap 4.1.2-0.22.9, the "phonegap build android" step says "Creating android project..." and then


Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.

Comment: when i created this in April i think it was a version 3.0 of phonegap. I will have to deal with it very soon and will post a solution

Comment: I was able to get the "phonegap build android" step to complete by defining ANDROID_HOME and then working through a series of other errors. Still, when I imported the project in Android Studio, I got a project that wouldn't build. For the time being, I'm going to stick with native Android Studio; I'm able to get "HelloWorld" running that way, at least.